NextJS Video loads only after full page load
im in a little dilemma right now. Basically I have a small video in the hero section. With ffmpeg and preload='auto' enabled (progressive download).
Issue being the placeholder renders but taking a look at chromes network tab it shows everything else down to the footers images/icons being loaded before the video even starts to buffer. Which on huge pages takes very long.
One solution is to use the play hook in the video to dynamically load the rest of the page afterwards:
  const Home = dynamic(() => import("../components/Home"));
  const [isPlaying, onPlay] = useState(false);


    return(
    <>
      <section className="hero">
        <video
          autoPlay
          muted
          loop
          playsInline
          onTimeUpdate={() => onPlay(true)}
          preload="auto"
        >
          <source src="/videos/hero.webm" type="video/webm" />
          <source src="/videos/hero.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
          "Your browser does not support the video tag."
        </video>
      </section>

      {isPlaying && (
          <Home />
      )}
    </>)

(using onTimeUpdate due to consistency reasons)
This works. However we want to use SSG to make the page crawl able and since we are using useState() this isn't possible any more even tho <Home/> is a server component.
Is there any way to make the Video load eager/before the rest of the content without affecting SSG capabilities?
